# How to configure rails app with apache2 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Below is my `000-default.conf` file in the following directory `etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav

  <Directory /var/www/webdav>
      DAV On
      AuthType Digest
      AuthName "webdav"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
      Require valid-user
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now locally i can access my files from server

and this is my .env file in rails app

```
WEBDAV_USER=username
WEBDAV_PASSWORD=password
WEBDAV_READ_URL=http://localhost/webdav
WEBDAV_WRITE_URL=http://localhost/webdav
```

but when I tries to perform some some operations with webdav from rails it gives me following error

```
CarrierWave::IntegrityError (Can't create a new collection:)
CarrierWave::IntegrityError (Can't download a new file:)
This server could not verify that you\nare authorized to access the   document\nrequested.  Either you supplied the wrong\ncredentials
```

I don't understand why it is giving this error because webdav server is working fine when i access it locally, but rails app is not able to access it.